# Some user friendly peer to peer selling app accepting cryptos?

Tags: android, ios, chat, cryptocurrency

### What I am looking for

I am searching for a user friendly peer to peer selling messaging (chat) app for selling and buying stuff with cryptocurrencies.

---

### Use case

Let's say I want to buy a camera. I see on any marketplace someone selling one that might interest me. I contact him and we pursue our deal on the messaging app (Whatsapp like for example) I am looking for to talk, negociate or whatever. And once we agree on the price and the crypto, we just make the deal inside the chat. Obviously we had our wallet addresses registered upon sign up.

---

### Why ?

The reason is that I am trying to reduce the amount of fiat currencies I use in my day to day life.

---

### Requirements

- Web or mobile app. If mobile, free to download but maybe with some fee per transaction.
- For iOS and Android users.
- User friendly. Let's say easy to use by someone with little or no knowledge in crypto trading or the blockchain technology.
- ETH and BTC support at very least.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: on what OS should the app run? How much may it cost?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it's done. What do you think ?

Comment: Clearer :) Just what mobile OS you have in mind in case of a mobile app? And do you really wish to use the very same address reused everytime (which is not what the "crypto philosophy" recommends)? Further, what crypto currencies should be supported? In principle, you could use any chat app for that. When agreed, the seller pastes an address which the buyer copies to initiate the transaction in his wallet.

Comment: Done again. Very instructive, I didn't know changing address was among the best practices as shown [in this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2045/should-i-use-a-different-address-for-every-transaction) but yeah totally make sense. I know it would be easy to do with any chat app. Just wanted to know if some chat had a crypto transaction feature embed in it.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such chat app existing, so chances are probably low (it eg raises the question how a deal is initiated: how does one get to know what's offered by whom). As for the addresses, it ideally would work together with some wallet app to pick one on sealing the deal, for the reasons given. // Thanks for editing once more, looks fine now! And: Good luck!